# Are there any API's or SDK's available to access data from CS 3D Imaging Software

Tags: python, api, sdk, medical-imaging

When provided with a CBCT scan, the Carestream 3D Imaging software produces cross-sectional views. I want to access these views directly in Python. Thus, I wanted to know if there are any SDK or APIs available for this exporting of data.

I tried searching the official Carestream website but to no avail